# Play Store says my Xamarin Android application needs a permission that IS NOT in the manifest

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, android-permissions

I've sent an application to the Google Play Store and the listing says it needs permission to access "Pictures/multimedia/files" but my AndroidManifest.xml doesn't have any attribute to request that permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="9" android:versionName="1.2.1" package="xxx">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="xxx" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></application>
</manifest>
```

Should I disable anything to stop asking for that permission? My apps doesn't need it!

Comment: Since Xamarin is using Internal Storage /External Storage ,your Application needs this Permission..

Comment: So, it's a core requirement for Xamarin to work, right?

Comment: No it is not a core requirement.... Are you using any 3rd-party libraries that are adding it?

Comment: @SushiHangover, I'm only using this NuGet package https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

Comment: Tried setting your project `Linking` option with `Sdk and User Assemblies`.